# "App not found, Please verify..." when launching from Visual Studio, but installs normally from Developer Portal

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm currently learning Teams development and I just installed the Teams Toolkit extension. Following the quickstart guide, launching the app opens my browser with the Teams web app and the message

> App not found, Please verify the app and it's[sic] access
> permissions.

Fortunately, this app **can** still be launched when selecting the "Preview in Teams" option **in the Developer Portal**.

Quoting the GettingStarted.txt:

> If you Start Debugging in a browser and Teams shows the message "App not found, Please verify the app and it's access permissions", **it means the app hasn't been uploaded to Teams Dev Portal**. To resolve this, follow the steps in the Quick start section above. The Project > TeamsFx > Configure for SSO menu command will do this step for you.

Except it **was** successfully uploaded to Dev Portal.

## What I did

- Did this "Configure for SSO" thing. No problems with that and the app was successfully added to the Developer Portal.

## Where I searched for an answer

- VS Marketplace page for Teams Toolkit (Reviews, Q&A)
- Github page (issues) for Teams Toolkit
- This very site - Stack Overflow.

Obviously, I'm not 100% sure that I haven't missed anything.

## Temporary solution

In the meantime, I set the "launchBrowser" property to "false" in launchSettings.json. However, it's a waste of time to constantly go back to the Developer Portal to launch it, especially when the functionality is there.

Visual Studio 2019, Microsoft Development Account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming nothing else was changed from the new project template, there are a few things you can try to narrow down the issue.

1. Open your browsers web dev tools and watch the console after clicking the Add button (before you see the error message). Sometimes a useful error message from the developer portal helps identify the issue.
2. Verify that when Visual Studio launches the URL, the correct tenant is loaded in Teams.
3. Run the project in VS, then manually navigate in your browser to the endpoint of your tab that you expect to work. It would be something like `https://localhost:44357/tab` by default (the value is in the manifest.json). The sample won't work completely because it's not running inside Teams, but you should be able to verify it's working locally.

If none of that helps, please log an issue on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues) and we can investigate a bug.

Answer (score 0):

We tried to repro this issue at our end and it is working fine for us. Could you please make sure app is opened in same tenant with which you configured for SSO. Also please remove all credentials from cache to make sure its not taking another credentials and try again.